# Icon Conditional Formatting in Percentage - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm applying a conditional formatting to a column (in %). I have a data filter by "Group" where at some data points color is not accurate while for the some other "Group" conditional formatting is working fine. I'm not sure about why it's not working properly at some data points. Have a look on the screen grab:-

[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a test report file with this issue? You can share the file using Google Drive.

Comment: @ashish1780 Did You find any workaround for This ? I am facing same situation please let me Know if you have found a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to change from percent to number and enter your rules as decimal numbers. Power Bi always treats percentage as decimal number (showing it as integer with % is just formatting thing). What is meant by "Percent" in conditional formatting is not the format of the rule you enter. When you use "Percent" it actually takes the values as a percentage of all the values. Since you're formatting based on the value itself, and not the value as a percentage of all the other values, you need to use "Number".

Sadly, there's 0 documentation about this from Microsoft (both for Power BI and Excel) it's always kind of implied.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft documentation, when dealing with percentages in a field, you need to provide numbers as decimals for the formatting rule. If percentages are provided instead, you end up setting the percentage of the overall range of values.

For more information, refer to this document:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting

The following sections should provide further clarification:

- [Color by rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting#color-by-rules)
- [Color by rules for percentages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting#color-by-rules-for-percentages)